# The execution failed. Please check error.log( In Madara Theme) Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, runtime-error, sample-data

I am getting this error in Madara Theme. I've turned on the debug mode and come to know about the error/warning that is given below:

> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in

Anyone here who know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Report the issue to whoever wrote that theme. does that error have afilename and line number with it?

Comment: yess there is a proper path and line number too. But I have checked that file. It contain only 10 lines of code and error line is in 3000.

Comment: home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/madara-unyson-backup-restore/framework/core/components/extensions/manager/class--fw-extensions-manager.php on line 3682

Comment: Please, always show us the complete error message not a summary

Comment: This is the complete error which I posted in a reply.

Comment: since my fastest php framework + micro framework as well  in the world is not avalable for download i can only reffer another microframework very fast that could replace that slower think will ruin your job : https://flightphp.com/

Comment: Is the plugin `madara-unyson-backup-restore` up to date? if not try updating it first. It seems the plugin code is not compatible with php 7.3+. `As of PHP 7.3, a warning will be thrown when continue is used within a switch without a numeric argument.` Ref: [php/php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/04e3523b7d095341f65ed5e71a3cac82fca690e4). Alternatively (not recommended) you could change all the `continue` in the switch statement

Comment: I'm using the Latest Version of all plugins